# Blender Cycles - Transparency Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

While working on the texture of a model I found a problem with my render.

[image]
As you can see here the mesh outline for the eyebrow can be seen and everything I've tried, I just can't seem to fix that one thing.

I used Blender Cycles and Blender 2.78.

[image]

Edit: Packed textures in .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am stumped. It doesn't seems to have a solution apart from pulling the eyebrow geometry slightly away from face. It seems the intersection created by the 2 meshes is causing the black lines.

Other things I've tried:

- Alpha Premultiply/Straight settings
- Render bounce and transmission settings
- Turning off all ray visibility expect for camera rays
- Texture clipping settings

Comment: Also scaling object up seems to resolve it. Why though - I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, just pulling the geometry 0.00001 on the Y-Axis is enough to fix it.